# What does it mean if aligned genomes are not of the same length?

Tags: sequence-alignment, genome, mauve

I am aligning 4 genomes of *Psuedomonas chlororaphis* using progressive mauve software. Command used:

```
progressiveMauve --output=outputfile --disable-backbone chl189.fas chl17415.fas chl50083.fas chlTAMOak81.fas
```

At the end, the resulting aligned genomes are not of the same length. What could be the potential problems?

[image]

This is a global alignment. Which is why im surprised that they aren't all the same length after alignment?
Also, while analysing the subsequent genomes, I noticed that some region which were present in only 2/4 genomes were misaligned in the end result. How do I proceed troubleshooting this problem?

I am a student and new to this field, could you please tell me how to proceed with manually checking to see whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I’ve seen cases like this. For me, there were plasmids at end that didn’t get aligned.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi @SethCommichaux please do remember to provide supporting information for your answer, i.e. not simply to confirm the OP's observation but offer a solution.